# BluetoothGattServer cancelConnection does not cancel the connection

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, gatt, android-ble

I have Android application which exposes BLE Server. I connect with [BluetoothGattServer#connect](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattServerCallback.html#onConnectionStateChange(android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice,%20int,%20int)). It works - my app gets call to [BluetoothGattServerCallback#onConnectionStateChange](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattServerCallback.html#onConnectionStateChange(android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice,%20int,%20int)) with [STATE_CONNECTED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothProfile.html#STATE_CONNECTED). When I'm done with the client I try to disconnect from my app with [BluetoothGattServer#cancelConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothProfile.html#STATE_CONNECTED).

**But I do not get call to [BluetoothGattServerCallback#onConnectionStateChange](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattServerCallback.html#onConnectionStateChange(android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice,%20int,%20int))** and it seems  that the connection is still active as my BLE client does not start to advertise (which it does when nothing is connected to it).

In logcat I see only:

```
BluetoothGattServer: cancelConnection() - device: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

The funny part is, my app gets call to [BluetoothGattServerCallback#onConnectionStateChange](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattServerCallback.html#onConnectionStateChange(android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice,%20int,%20int)) with [STATE_DISCONNECTED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothProfile.html#STATE_DISCONNECTED) as soon as I turn off BT completely.

Similar issues in Google's tracker: [63461](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&groupby=&sort=&id=63461) and [63464](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63464).

Comment: iirc cancelConnection is completely broken on most of the early devices when Android ble first come out and Google decided not to fix that.

Comment: Did you manage to find a fix for this? I'm struggling with the same thing

Comment: Nope - I decided to move as away from BLE as I can and never come close again.

Answer (score 10):

When newState==BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED, you have to call BluetoothGattServer.connect();.

```
@Override
public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothDevice device, int status, int newState) {
    super.onConnectionStateChange(device, status, newState);
    if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED){
        mDevice = device;
        mBluetoothGattServer.connect(device, false);
    }else {
        mDevice = null;
    }
}

private void cancelConnection(){
    if (mDevice != null) {
        mBluetoothGattServer.cancelConnection(mDevice);
    }
}
```

Comment: you wrote that based on what?

Comment: [63461](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36985764)#8, add I used it.

Comment: #16 says: Samsung S8+ running Android version 8.0.0 and Samsung Experience version 9.0 does not work for comment 8.
HTC running Android version 8.0.0 does not work either.

Comment: Oh, I can work with Pixel-8.1 as peripheral. Didn't try Samsung phones.

Answer (score 2):

Encountering same issue when calling disconnect() method.. no disconnect is given in onConnectionStateChange in my BluetoothGattCallback.

Cycling Bluetooth seems the be the only thing that works.

edit:
also, after disconnect() and close() method are called, I am still connected according to this code:

```
public int getConnectedBLEDevices() {
        int i = 0;
        List<BluetoothDevice> devices = mBluetoothManager.getConnectedDevices(BluetoothProfile.GATT);
        for(BluetoothDevice device : devices) {
            if(device.getType() == BluetoothDevice.DEVICE_TYPE_LE) {
                Logs.writeEvent(TAG+".getConnectedBLEDevices()", device.getAddress() + "\n"+ getStateAsString(mBluetoothManager.getConnectionState(device, BluetoothProfile.GATT)));
                i++;
            }
        }
        return i;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Cycling Bluetooth seems the be the only thing that works. "?

Comment: Turning the bluetooth on and off

Comment: Did you manage to find a fix for this? I'm struggling with the same thing

Answer (score 0):

pls see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37127644

Status: Won't Fix (Intended Behavior)
You must call BluetoothGattServer.connect() to mark connection as used, then BluetoothGattServer.disconnect() to mark it as no longer used. Then after a timeout stack can decide to disconnect from the remote if no one else is using the connection.
If BluetoothGattServer.connect() is not called after the connection is established, then the stack is keeping the connection until some gatt client/server app start using this connection.

Comment: There is no such method BluetoothGattServer.disconnect()